# Siliently upgrade worklight 5.0.6.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I installed worklight 5.0.6 on a Linux system using silient mode. Now, I want to upgrade worklight server to 5.0.6.1 using silient mode as well.

Does Worklight allow silient upgrade ? If yes, is there any guidance for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IBM Worklight Server 5.0.5 or newer supports silent upgrade, just like silent install.

The procedure is the same as [documented](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/admin/t_silent_installation.html) in the IBM Worklight manual:

1. Do the same operation (in this case, an upgrade 5.0.6 -> 5.0.6.1) on a machine that has a usable GUI, using the Installation Manager wizard, and using the option '-record *responseFile*'.
2. Modify the settings in the response file so that it matches the target machine.
3. Execute the response file on the target machine, using the `imcl` command.